# Firebase auth setPersistance({type: 'SESSION'}) throws INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Expected a class definition

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm trying to implement a **"remember me"** checkbox in my login form.

I created the project with `Angular CLI 12.2.9`, `firebase 9.4.0` and `@angular/fire 7.4.0`

I have the following service `auth.service.ts`

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Auth } from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(private auth: Auth) {
    
  }

  public async setPersistence(persistence: boolean): Promise<void> {
    if (persistence) {
      await this.auth.setPersistence({ type: 'SESSION' });
    } else {
      await this.auth.setPersistence({ type: 'NONE' });
    }
  }
}
```

The Persistance interface in `@angular/fire/auth` is the following:

```
/**
 * An interface covering the possible persistence mechanism types.
 *
 * @public
 */
export declare interface Persistence {
    /**
     * Type of Persistence.
     * - 'SESSION' is used for temporary persistence such as `sessionStorage`.
     * - 'LOCAL' is used for long term persistence such as `localStorage` or `IndexedDB`.
     * - 'NONE' is used for in-memory, or no persistence.
     */
    readonly type: 'SESSION' | 'LOCAL' | 'NONE';
}
```

For some reason when I call `setPersistence` in my component I get the following error:

[image]

This is my component:

```
import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { emailRegex } from './email.regex';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  public login: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private auth: AuthService) {
    this.login = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(emailRegex)]],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      rememberMe: false,
    });
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.login.get("rememberMe")?.valueChanges.subscribe((p: boolean) => {
      this.auth.setPersistence(p).then((res) => {
        console.log("Changed success");

      })
    });
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? And if this is not the correct way to change the User auth persistence please guide me through the correct path. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by making the following imports:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import {
  Auth,
} from '@angular/fire/auth';

import {
  setPersistence,
  inMemoryPersistence,
  browserSessionPersistence,
  Persistence,
} from '@firebase/auth';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    private auth: Auth,
  ) {

  }


  public async setPersistence(persistence: boolean): Promise<void> {
    const type: Persistence = persistence
      ? browserSessionPersistence
      : inMemoryPersistence;

    await setPersistence(this.auth, type);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any ideas? `No provider for auth`

Answer (score 0):

it seems it expect objects, that are already in library. for example:

```
.setPersistance(Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
```